# Continuous Form (ms Access 2003)

Tags: ms-access

I am displaying the results of a query in a continuous form. The query can generate a variable number of fields. I have been looking at ways to suppress non-active fields through setting their visible properties to No, however, a gap still appears where these fields are in the displayed form.

Is there any way I can push fields together to remove such gaps (when fields are not in use)?

I could manually create a new form in VBA for each query but that might seem excessive if there was an easier way.

Comment: I had similar task, looks like there is no automatic way for this. I moved visible fields by VBA code. Creating new fields didn't work for me because the application should work in compiled state. I created maximum possible number of fields.

Comment: Are you opposed to setting the form to display in Datasheet  instead of Continuous Forms view?

Comment: Many thanks again for everyone's help here. I don't mind the use of Datasheets...they're very easy to use, convenient and auto expand/contract according to the query. So they tick many boxes. I'm probably getting a bit mixed up (through inexperience)  when I hear the preference of many in Google land of Continuous Forms over Datasheet use. The extra presentation possibilities in Continuous Forms (txt centre, back colour, etc.) appears attractive, though. However, Datasheets offer their own advantages, so I should probably leave things as they are and focus on other things at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way is to join fields together in a string in the query itself so that only one field for provided for display on the form.

Unfortunately Continuous Forms are a bit of a mish mash, and as a result have some interesting side effects.  For instance although you can have different values per row if the field is bound, as soon as you unbind it, every row is the same for that field.

Comment: Many thanks for your thoughts. As above, I'll stick to Datasheets and leave Continuous Forms for the now (Datasheet use, in reality, probably ticks all boxes required) and focus on additional useful functionality.